# next.js error: Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js

I'm trying to deploy a nextJs app but when I run `npm run build` I see some of the errors listed below:

Build error occurred
Error:

> Build failed because of webpack errors
> at /Users/hassan/Upwork/ROCProjectNext.js/ROCNext/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async /Users/hassan/Upwork/ROC Project Next.js/ROC- Next/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:1:525
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! admin-1.0@0.1.0 build: `next build`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the admin-1.0@0.1.0 build script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/hassan/.npm/_logs/2021-04-07T06_52_28_325Z-debug.log

any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe problem in your `package.json` file, check this one.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check your `nextjs` version in `package.json` file it is upgraded to latest version. Downgrade the version of `nextjs` it will help you to avoid this error.

Comment: I am getting a similar error. npm run build works but next build returns "Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/ProgramData/nvm/v16.4.2/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'D:\App\nextjs-blog'
> Build failed because of webpack errors"
I ensured net is the same version globally (in programeData) and locally for my project (in D:/App)